# Can I apply for an ESTA while I have a pending US visa application for my second non-VWP eligible passport?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, dual-nationality

One month ago, I applied for a US visa using a non-VWP passport and have been selected for administrative processing (no luck I know).

Now, I have a new passport from a VWP country. Can I apply for an ESTA and travel to the US with no issues?

I am travelling for medical surgery.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for an ESTA for sure. However, the form will ask for the details of your other passport, and the ESTA may or may not be denied once the match is found in the system.

If it is approved, you should be fine at the border, but answer any questions truthfully as usual.